# How to send ZOHO SMTP server mail in java?

Tags: java, smtp

I have been using ZOHO SMTP server for sending out email. but it was working in localhost server ,when deploying my code into AWS server it not going to be working,it is giving Exception like below..

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.zoho.com, port: 465;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

My java code is :-

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.zoho.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);

        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", username);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", password);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        // prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        // prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        // prop.setProperty("mail.smtps.tls.enable", "true");
```

The above code is working in my localhost server (Tomcat).
can any one please help to solve out this.

Answer (score 0):

465 is SSL port. It looks like SSL certificate from ZOHO is missing in AWS. Download/obtain certificate from Zoho and import it on AWS's Keystore. It should solve the problem.
Check https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/ssl-security-certificate-updated-pop-imap-and-smtp-servers from similar problem and possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you NaveenBharadwaj. can you please tell me that how to Download/obtain certificate from Zoho and import it on AWS's Keystore. Is thair any process to do for getting  SSL certificate from ZOHO.

Comment: You need to check existing certificates in AWS. As I read some articles, Zoho SSL certificate needs to be purchased. It is not free. May be AWS has already done it for you. It is necessary to check. If not, it will cost you extra.

Comment: The point is, when you connected from localhost, it was using HTTP. As soon as you deployed in AWS (uses HTTPS), the communication became "secure". And because of the absence of certificate, this communication was not successful as there was no handshake. And hence the exception.